# Handling GZIP Compression using WININET API's

Tags: c, winapi, com, ole, wininet

My Server sends me a JSON data stream which is compressed using GZIP Compression.

When I request this data on the normal IE Browser, I get the data and when I mention the application to open with, The Browser automatically decompresses that data stream and shows me my JSON data.

My C Application is using COM/OLE to embed an IE Browser Instance and I am using WININET for GET/POST operations So here I get the data compressed.

Since its IE Browser Functionality that decompresses the GZIP data automatically in the case of the default IE browser 
How can I get the data decrypted automatically via WININET in my C Application?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Starting Vista, `INTERNET_OPTION_HTTP_DECODING` flag enables gzip decoding within WinInet:

[INTERNET_OPTION_HTTP_DECODING](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385328%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> Enables WinINet to perform decoding for the gzip and deflate encoding schemes. For more information, see [Content Encoding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383955%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).
>
> When decoding fails, the application has two options: it can remove the Accept-Encoding header and resend the request, or it can set the INTERNET_OPTION_HTTP_DECODING option on the request to false and then resend the request. If the decoding option is set to false, the application must check the Content-Encoding header and perform any decoding at the application level.

In earlier version of Windows you would have to decompress yourself (which is also reasonably easy using e.g. http://zlib.net/)

Comment: `Internet Explorer 7` decompress the `GZIP` Data in `WinXP` .How does that happen?

Comment: It might have been possibly added with `IE7`. The point is that some XPs might still be not having it readily available (if you for any reason target all XPs). And IE7 is already included into Vista http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer#OS_compatibility

Comment: Thanks i am targeting Windows XP with SP 2 and above. Will try it out.

Comment: Setting the `INTERNET_OPTION_HTTP_DECODING` flag in the  `SetInternetOption` WININET API worked. Thanks @Roman R.

Comment: Thanks. Just an additional note: Set this option before you open the http request. Not later.